# modify strings in pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, string, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I want to make all strings lower case and remove the whitespaces at the beginning and end of the strings.

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(data=[1,2,3,'A'],columns=['A'])
df['A'] = numpy.where(
    df['A'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str)),
    df['A'].str.lower().str.strip(),
    df['A'],
)
```

The problem is that the code above fails if none of the rows is a string.

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(data=[1,2,3],columns=['A'])
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas
```

Is there a better way to do this than

```
for index in df['A'].index:
    if isinstance(df['A'].iloc[index], str):
        df['A'].iloc[index] = df['A'].iloc[index].str.lower().str.strip()
```

Comment: I think it is ugly bug :(

Comment: Use `df['A']=df['A'].apply(lambda x: x.lower().strip() if isinstance(x, str) else x)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want to leave your non strings untouched, you can use:

```
df['A']=df['A'].apply(lambda x: x.lower().strip() if isinstance(x, str) else x)
```